# Why does character trim work for get_the_excerpt and not for the_excerpt?

Tags: php, wordpress

So I am wishing to trim the excerpt for a specific loop and it was all working fine until I imported a load of posts for that category loop. Now the excerpt trim is not working and only seems to work if I use $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();

Any ideas?

```html
<?php $excerpt = the_excerpt(array ( 'class' => 'custom-excerpt'));
            echo substr( $excerpt, 0, 100); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`get_the_excerpt()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_excerpt/) returns the text so you can capture it and modify the contents.

[`the_excerpt()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/) outputs the content so it is echo'd out and you are not actually receiving the text.

If you have to use `the_excerpt()` you can use [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) to capture the output and then massage the data as necessary:

```
ob_start();
the_excerpt(array ( 'class' => 'custom-excerpt'));
$excerpt = ob_get_clean();
$excerpt = substr( $excerpt, 0, 100);
```

Comment: Did you echo `$excerpt`?

Comment: Oh right of course. Thanks. Although now the '...' have disappeared and it just cuts off. Without the dots it would better to cut it by words. Would you recommend cutting it by words or inserting the dots?

Comment: The dots are a universal way to say that text has been cut off so that would be my recommendation

Comment: If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answer-er and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.